# Troubles with getDay in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi this seems simple enough but it's not working! I am trying to take two Epoch numbers and calculate the day of the week in a loop for that current day.  I need this because I want to not count the days that are on the weekend (i.e. 0 or 6).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to display todays day of the week.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var oneDay = 86400;
    var days = 0;
    var currDay = 0;
    //var d = new Date();
    // get the start time in Epoch
    var dayTime = 1425531600 //from the user selection
    var endTime = 1425960000

    //while our dayTime is less than the end time,
    //loop through the days and count them.
    while (dayTime < endTime) {
        // advance one day
        dayTime = dayTime + oneDay;
        document.write("out:"+dayTime+"<br>")

        //turn the new time in Epoch into a date
        var d = new Date(dayTime);
        document.write("out:"+d.getDay()+"<br>")

    }

    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The output looks like this:

```
    out:1425618000
    out:6
    out:1425704400
    out:6
    out:1425790800
    out:6
    out:1425877200
    out:6
    out:1425963600
    out:6
```

Why am I ALWAYS getting '6' for each Epoch?   Something wrong with my Epoch values? Note, it's 5 days so each day is 86400 long.

I copied the code into this page to test it:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_getday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `new Date(x)`, `x` needs to be in unixEpoch format *(milliseconds)* - or [*other formats*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). To solve your problem, just multiply all your values by `1000`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oneDay = 86400000;
  var days = 0;
  var currDay = 0;
  //var d = new Date();
  // get the start time in Epoch
  var dayTime = 1425531600000 //from the user selection
  var endTime = 1425960000000

  //while our dayTime is less than the end time,
  //loop through the days and count them.
  while (dayTime < endTime) {
    // advance one day
    dayTime = dayTime + oneDay;
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',"out:" + dayTime + "<br>")

    //turn the new time in Epoch into a date
    var d = new Date(dayTime);
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',"out:" + d.getDay() + "<br>")

  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks ... I did NOT see that one.. ha ha. I owe you !